# Reading multiple files?

Tags: perl

how can i read multiple files in perl and store them in a hash?

Thanks.

Comment: can you give an example of what you're trying and what doesn't work?

Comment: how are you specifying the files - a list of names or a glob (wildcard)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
my %data;
my @FILES = @ARGV;
# or maybe   @FILES = glob("some/directory/*.ext");
```

Since this is Perl, there are many ways to do it.

```
# 1. Open and load each file    
foreach my $file (@FILES) {
    local $/ = undef;
    open my $fh, '<', $file;
    $data{$file} = <$fh>;
}

# 1b. Using  map
%data = map { 
   local $/=undef;
   open my $fh, '<', $file;
   my $data = <$fh>;
   $_ => $data
} @FILES;

# 2. Leverage your operating system
foreach my $file (@FILES) {
    $data{$file} = qx(/bin/cat "$file");
}

# 3. Use a module
use File::Slurp;
foreach my $file (@FILES) {
    $data{$file} = File::Slurp::slurp($file);
}

# 3b, using  map
use File::Slurp;
%data = map { $_ => File::Slurp::slurp($_) } @FILES;
```

Comment: +1 Regarding the first two options - what about closing these files? (I know this is not strictly required). Does Perl have something like Ruby's File.open() { } which automatically closes the file?

Comment: Lexical filehandles (the ones you declare with my, ala my $fh, but not just FH) close automatically when they go out of scope - And all of his examples do!

Comment: Now this is some sexy perl, I especially like the second solution, although had the third one not be platform dependent, that one would have been my favorite (looks elegant :))

Answer (score 4):

See this perlfaq entry: [How can I read in an entire file all at once?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-can-I-read-in-an-entire-file-all-at-once?)

A hash can be created like this:

```
my %hash = (
    filename => $file_content,
    # ...
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my %data;
foreach my $fn (@ARGV) {
    open (my $IN, $fn) or die "couldn't open $fn: $!";
    $data{$fn} = join "", <$IN>;
    close $fn;
}

foreach my $key (keys %data) {
    print "File $key:\n$data{$key}\n\n\n";
}
```

The code iterates over a list of file names, in this case passed in as command line arguments in @ARGV.  For each filename, it opens a file handle and reads from it in array context, which loads each line of the file as an element of the array.  In this case, we're reading to an anonymous array which is passed into join.  Join glues the elements of the array together, in this case with the empty string as a separator.  The result, one string with the entire file contents, is then stored in the hash with the filename as the key.  The second loop just prints the results.

Note that for large files, this is a good way to run yourself out of memory fast.  Think about ways to process your data in a streaming mode.

Comment: @Nathan Fellman - Matter of style, I suppose.  I did it this way since it could be directly translated to a function rather than relying on the filenames being in @ARGV.  Also, I didn't feel like looking up how to get the name of the file currently being read in that idiom.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all the files are in `@ARGV`, for instance if they're commandline arguments, you can iterate over them all like this:

```
@array = ();
while (<>) {
    push @array, $_;
    # or any other manipulation on the lines
    # for instance extracting a key and value from
    # the line and putting them into a hash
}
```